# Change group policy using windows CMD

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, windows-update, group-policy, wsus

I want to change the group policy setting that applies the value of the Windows Update WSUS server location `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUServer` and `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUStatusServer`.

Changing them directly in the registry will not overwrite what has been set in the group policy, so I would like to know, what commands can I use to change the group policy input of these values instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Mark Russinovich has an excellent article on circumventing Group Policy changes](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/circumventing-group-policy-settings/ba-p/723353).

> Group policy settings are an integral part of any Windows-based IT environment. If you’re a network administrator you use them to enforce corporate security and desktop management policy, and if you’re a user you’ve almost certainly been frustrated by the limitations imposed by those policies. Regardless of which you are, you should be aware that if the users in your network belong to the local administrator’s group they can get around policies any time they want.
>
> There are two steps to circumventing a group policy setting: identifying the setting’s location and preventing the setting from being applied. There are many group policy references available, but since machine group policy settings store in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE branch of the Registry and per-user group policy settings store in HKEY_CURRENT_USER, if you don’t know the location of the setting that’s preventing you from doing something you want you can use Regmon to find it.
>
> The number of desktop lockdown settings available to group policy administrators is enormous. They can prevent you from doing anything from changing your desktop appearance and start menu to running certain applications. Two commonly applied settings include a pre-configured screen saver program so that users don’t waste resources on frivolous screen savers, and a screen saver timeout so that systems aren’t left indefinitely accessible when a user steps away. When these settings are in effect Windows omits the screen saver tab of display properties control panel applet or doesn’t let you modify the screen saver or its timeout. I’m going to show you how to use the power of being a local administrator and Regmon to track down these settings and override them on your own system.

While it goes into the Registry Monitor, [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) also exists these days which combines several monitoring tools into one. It allows you to find the registry keys that are being modified. Just jump to the relevant registry keys and change their permissions such that they can't be updated anymore...

Check out what you can do with the `reg` command; you can verify access with [`accesschk`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922).

Comment: Thanks for the method, Tom. But it captures too much data when dealing with changes made by `gpedit.msc`. I think this is rather a different question, so I have opened a new thread here: http://superuser.com/questions/946123/how-can-i-use-process-monitor-to-detect-register-changes-made-by-gpedit-modifica

Answer (score 10):

The following tool, from **Microsoft TechNet**, allows management of **Group Policy** via the command line, and thus scripting as well:

**[Local Group Policy Object Utility, v1.0](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/)**

Answer (score 7):

Group policy for the local machine is stored in the registry.

The lame approach for modifying it, is via the Command Prompt using the reg command. This is less than practical because it requires absolute knowledge of each and every local policy registry setting, and errors here may be quite disastrous.

The tool to use instead is [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx), Microsoft's successor to the Command Prompt.

Some articles that can start you on the way to using [PowerShell cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for local policy changes are :

[Use Windows PowerShell to Manage Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759177.aspx)
[Windows PowerShell Cmdlets for Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd367856%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
[Group Policy management for IT pros](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Group-Policy-management-for-IT-pros)
[Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732)
[Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25250)

Comment: As appealing as the PowerShell GroupPolicy cmdlet seems, apparently (and surprisingly) it cannot be used in the simplest case, namely, to manage local machine or user policies on a non-domain joined machine. Indeed your first link states that the cmdlet requires AD, but before noticing this, I struggled to get the GP cmdlet working using on a standalone Windows 10 Pro client and latest PowerShell. I was encouraged at first that RSAT (a prerequisite of the GP cmdlet) installed successfully, but in the end, the cmdlet was never satisfied with the strength of the local Administrator credentials.

Comment: @GlennSlayden, could you please tell more about your tensions? You installed RSAT but anyway failed because you machine wasn't in the domain, because of weakness of your password? Why?

Comment: @Suncatcher My best guess is that it was because it’s a standalone machine with no domain. As I mentioned, I originally either did not notice this requirement (or perhaps didn’t believe it would be a showstopper).

Comment: As far as I tested, changing Registry Keys has no effect on the appropriate Group Policies.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can run `gpedit.msc`. As in <kbd>Start - r</kbd> `gpedit.msc` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Please read que. properly... You ans. is funny ..... :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this policy:

```
Network security: Force logoff when logon hours expire
```

It is (on GPEDIT.MSC) on:

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options
```

How to change it from command line?

The tittle of the post say:

> Change group policy using windows CMD

So i thought it would explain how to change group policy using windows CMD (to include it on a BATCH file), any group policy !!!

thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).